# How to completely disable byte queue limits (bql) in linux?

Tags: networking

I want to do some analysis that requires fixed values for the driver queue to test starvation and latency. Is there a way to disable the BQL so it does not affect the driver queue in linux?

I can't revert to old kernels because of some dependancies in other tools.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: version 20.04.5 LTS